# How to get resource bundle file from a directory in java?

Tags: java, internationalization

I have a code to internationalize an application. I need to load the bundle file, go back twice from the running location and load it.

My code is,

```
bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("../../resources/basic",new Locale("fr", "CA"));
lblUsername.setText(bundle.getString("username"));
lblPassword.setText(bundle.getString("password"));
btnLogin.setText(bundle.getString("login"));
```

I got the following error.

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name ../../resources/basic, locale fr_CA
at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
at com.daycare.ui.user.Login$4.itemStateChanged(Login.java:248)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source)
at com.daycare.ui.user.Login.<init>(Login.java:372)
at com.daycare.ui.user.Login$1.run(Login.java:104)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I give the correct path of budle file?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: does your bundle exists at specified location, what is the name of your resource bundle

Comment: does basic_fr_CA.properties exists at the specified location

Comment: Yes exist. File name is basic. It is a properties file

Comment: Terminology please. `ResourceBundles` are in *packages,* i.e. folders in a JAR file; not directories. This may help clarify things for you.

Answer (score 10):

As far as I remember the `Bundle` class will lookup by default on the current `ClassLoader` to find your resource. If you want to look a file on the filesystem, please use that instead:

```
File file = new File("the path of the folder containing the bundles");
URL[] urls = new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()};
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("the bundle name", your_locale, loader);
```

Comment: I got this error. java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name basic, locale en_US

Comment: Can you try with an absolute path for the bundle directory, rather than relative as described in you post.

Comment: And you're sure your file is called **basic_en_US.properties** ?

Comment: Yes. Sure. It is basic_en_US

Comment: it has to end up with **.properties**

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("../../resources/basic",new Locale("fr", "CA"));
```

change the first argument to   fully qualified class name and make sure that basic_fr_CA.properties exists.

for example 
if your file is at

```
/resource/basic_fr_CA.properties location,
```

then change your java code to

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.basic",new Locale("fr", "CA"));
```

Comment: if your file is at /resource/basic_fr_CA.properties location, then change your java code to  ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.basic",new Locale("fr", "CA"));

Comment: I did. but same error. java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name basic, locale fr_CA

Comment: is your resources folder in classpath. Also if the resource bundle is in the same directory as the class, remove all the path information.

Comment: Yes. My resource folder contains basic.properties, basic_en_US.properties, basic_fr_CA.properties files and a jpg image named, MainLogo. That's it

Comment: check for typos resources and resource folder are different

Comment: have a look at the following tutorial on resource bundle hope this will help in resolving your problem http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-locales-and-resource-bundles-to-internationalize-my-application.html

Answer (score 0):

If your resource is in resources folder, you can use this way, which is better in that you do not have to deal with checked exceptions:

```
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{ I18NManager.class.getResource("path to folder containing bundles you want to load")});
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("the bundle name", locale);
```

where `I18NManager` represents class which is loading resource.

`I18NManager.class` can be replaced with `getClass()` if it is not in static context.